# } expected even though i have it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to this language, actually I'm new in programming and I'm trying to create a simple function but for some reason my `{` and `}` are messed up.

[image: Visual Studio screenshot of code]

I know that i'm probably doing something stupid most likely but I have no clue on what to search in order to find the answer.

Comment: Is there more code above your shared code screenshot?

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code, but include the code itself.

Comment: @marc_s: Seriously? The image will be up as long as the question. Seeing the red markers actually enrich the question.

Comment: @jgauffin: agreed - here, for once, it actually makes sense to have the screenshot - but the code as such, as text, would still be helpful, too. Downvote removed

Comment: Side note: I'd suggest not naming a variable `var`. It'll work, but it also has special meaning (it infers the type when you don't specify one) and will most probably end up causing confusion.

Comment: We should post questions as text rather than images because images are not searchable, and are not visible on some browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```
public byte var = 5;
```

You shouldn't have written `public` there. `var` is in a method so it is a local variable. Local variables cannot have access modifiers because their scope is just the surrounding method, no one else can access it.

The word `public` confuses the compiler. It thinks that the method is a class when it is clearly not, hence the error. Just remove `public`.

Answer (score 2):

The `public` access modifier cannot be used on local variables, such as the one in your `start` function.

Answer (score 1):

A local variable cannot have access modifier on it. You are using "public" access modifier with the local variable. This is wrong. Remove public and it will work.